# Date and Time pickers to Timestamp field

Tags: php, date, datepicker, type-conversion, timepicker

I have a date field and a time field which both have their own pickers.  One that has the calendar popup and the other has the time popup.  Now I have the calendar's format: dd/mm/yyyy now for some reason when I try to save the inputted values i get:

```
1969-12-31 00:00:00
```

So I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I've read every post I've found here on converting string to timestamp and nothing doing.  Here's the code I have:

```
$mydatetime = strip_tags($_POST['datefield']) . ' ' . strip_tags($_POST['timefield']);
$mydatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($mydatetime));
```

any help please?

Comment: What does `var_dump($mydatetime);` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> $mydatetime = str_replace('/','-', strip_tags($_POST['datefield'])) . ' ' 
>                 . strip_tags($_POST['timefield']);
> $mydatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($mydatetime));
> ```

`strtotime` waiting format `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`. In your case better transform to `dd-mm-yyyy`

Answer (score 2):

this is the only code you need (anything else is redundant):

```
    $mydatetime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$_POST[datefield] $_POST[timefield]"));
```